# How to select a date based on another date in plain Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please no PL/SQL here. This is for pure Oracle SQL only. 11g.

So if at script level I have a bind variable that is a Date, let's say :current_date, how can I, based on that variable select another date based on an algorithm and then use that result in other queries.

This is bugging me I can't seem to come up with a solution.

The algorithm is this:

If :current_date is Monday, make our wanted variable be the previous Friday, if not just make our wanted variable point to :current_date - 1.

So with this example, how would I accomplish this? Keep in mind that the goal is to use this in other virtual tables in the query.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "other virtual tables in the query"? Do you have several queries you're running together as a script; or one query with inline views or CTEs?

Comment: The first, several queries that I run together. So I need a WITH that gives me two variables that result from that algorithm, one that is based on my bind var and the other that is created 'recursively' after this last result. Then these two results I need to use like you would a bind variable in a script. Use them in logical comparisons etc...

Comment: You could use substitution variables, but you would end up converting between dates and strings a lot. Why not repeat the calculation (e.g. Gordon's case) in each query? (You could put that whole thing into a substitution variable to avoid repetition I suppose, but that would be unusual). Where is current_date coming from, and is it really a date - is that defined with a `variable` command and populated from an anonymous block?

Comment: That is the main problem, in DECODEs and TO_CHARs  I'm easily going to go into trouble. It has happened before with something somewhat similar. I was hoping someone knew a clever way to bypass all this.

Comment: current_date is always a valid DATE in a specified Oracle format.

Comment: @user3046061 except when current_date is preceded by a colon (`:`) as it is here, in which case Oracle SQL Developer treats it as a named Bind variable of type string.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like pretty simple date arithmetic:

```
select (case when to_char(:current_date, 'D') = '1'
             then :current_date - 3
             else :current_date - 1
        end)
```

You can use `interval` as well for the time periods.

Comment: and then what is a trick to use this and create another date variable based on THIS result?  It's more what I'm aiming at... in the end.

Comment: @user3046061 . . . This creates another column.  Your question says explicitly that you don't want a PL/SQL solution, but "variables" live in PL/SQL.  Columns live in SQL (so to speak).  You can use `into` to assign this value to a variable.

Comment: That is how you assign a variable in a PL/SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code in SQL Developer as as script rather than as a statement, you can use syntax from SQL*Plus for declaring bind variables of various types.

Unfortunately `DATE` is not a supported data type for bind variables in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer

> ```
> Usage: VAR[IABLE] [  [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
> VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
> NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | REFCURSOR |
> BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
> where n is a positive integer
> ```

The following code run as a script in SQL Developer:

```
var my_bind varchar2;
exec :my_bind := sysdate;
select :my_bind from dual;
exec select 'test' into :my_bind from dual;
select :my_bind from dual;
```

Generates the following output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


:MY_BIND                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-JUL-2015 13:49:54                                                            


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


:MY_BIND
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test
```

This still doesn't help with dates though since you'll still be stuck with character strings that you will need to cast to and from dates with to_date and to_char.